# Is it possible to read the Mac keyboard when running on the iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is it possible (even with a horrible kludge) to read the Mac's keyboard input while running an  iPad app?

I'm making a level editor for a game I'm working on and it needs to run on the iPad simulator app, but I'd like to be able to read keys for quick short cuts.  This app will never run on the iPad and will never be submitted to the app store.

Thanks, Roger.

Comment: Why?

Wouldn't it be easier to have the level editor be a regular OS X application?

Comment: Is it not possible to simulate an iPad with connected keyboard-dock?

Comment: Chinmay, it's possible to simulate a hardware keyboard, but that doesn't necessarily mean it'll respond to keys like the ctrl, alt and cmd keys. Roger, as Williham said, it'd be a better idea to build the editor as a Mac application. It can use the same code.